# How to post a variable value from javascript to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

I am using JavaScript to pass a variable to another php file.  I have a value in javascript, and I want to pass it as a post variable to another php file.

Javascript code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

//Important code here to post a variable to bh.php:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#op_comp_id').load('bh.php').show();
    $('#get_value_id').keyup(function() {
    $.post('bh.php', { id: form.get_value.value },
        function(result){
            $('#op_comp_id').html(result).show();
            });  
    });
});
</script>

</head> 
<body>
<?$id = $_GET['id'];?>
<form  name="form">
<input type="text" id="get_value_id" name="get_value" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
</input>
</form>

<div id="op_comp_id"></div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

This was my attempt to pass a variable value from javascript to `bh.php` in post mode.

```
bh.php?id=value
```

Is there an alternative way or better way to do this?

Comment: @hRaval Yes  the the url should be bh.php?id=value

Comment: If you will use keyup event after every keypress for letter ajax will be called. You can also use blur event.

Answer (score 4):

Use following method to pass a JavaScript variable to php with a post:

```
 $(input[name=get_value]).bind('keyup click blur focus change paste',function(){ 
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({    
                    type: "POST",                                  
                    url: "bh.php",
                    async: false,
                    data: "clientId="+id ,
                    success:function(response){
                    $('#op_comp_id').html(response).show();

                    }                        
                });
               }
```

**bh.php** use following code

```
<?php
 $id = $_REQUEST['clientId'];
 // your code
?>
```

Comment: Thx for reply ... is there a way i can use it in hidden field of form ... where value comes from variable`<input type="hidden" id="get_value_id" name="get_value" value="<?$echo $id?>"></input>`

Comment: @Harinder yes you can , simple don't use id , use "name"$(input[name=textboxname])" so you can use in any textbox , and there is no need"</input>" tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hidden Inputfields with javascript. The javascript gets the value via getElementbyId and replace it with the value of a hidden input (also with getElementbyId). Then javascript automaticly submit the form with the hidden input in it (document.forms["formID"].submit();). Thats it. The Value will be send via the form method. So you can send it via post very easy.